# Print elements of ndarray in their storage order

Tags: python, numpy

To check whether my assumptions on memory layout are correct, I'd sometimes like to print elements of an `ndarray` exactly in the storage order in memory.

I know `flatten`, `ravel`, `flat`, `flatiter` but I'm still not sure which function will **truly** reflect the memory order?

Comment: If you care about such things, why are you using Python?

Comment: So maybe because I have/plan to use a C binding? Because I'm just interested what happens under the hood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `ravel` will suit your needs, if you use the `order='K'` option. From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

> order : {‘C’,’F’, ‘A’, ‘K’}, optional
>
> [...] ‘K’ means to read the elements in the order they occur in memory, except for reversing the data when strides are negative.[...]

If you just want to learn more about the memory layout of an array without printing all the elements, you can look at its [`strides` attribute](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html).

Comment: `flatten` also takes the `order` parameter.  But `ravel` is used more often.